# SVN commit batch file using argument

Tags: batch-file, svn

I want to use a batch file to run an svn commit and pass an argument for the comment. E.g.:

```
svn commit test.file -m %1
```

I get missing argument when I use this.

And if I use the following:

```
svn commit test.file -m "%1"
```

...it ignores anything I enter on the command line and enters a blank comment.

Do any of you know how I can pass the comment at run-time?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Hey Bahrep

When I use svn commit test.file -m %1
SVN returns "missing argument"

When I use svn commit test.file -m "%1"
it ignores any comments made at the CmdLine

thanks Tony

Comment: Have you tried `-m "%~1"`?

Comment: Hi aschipfl, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi aschipfl, thanks for the suggestion.

Here's my .bat file - 

svn commit local.cf -m "%~1"
pause

This returns the following - 

svn commit local.cf -m ""
svn: E155007: 'C:\Users\aabrahams\Desktop\batfiles\local.cf' is not a working copy

Running the commit manually works fine.

Any further help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Rgds
Tony

Comment: Hi again.

So, I fixed the working copy error message....

Here's the .bat file - 

svn commit C:\LocalCF\local.cf -m "%~1"
pause

And i'm still not able to send data from the CmdLine, it commits with a blank comment.

Thanks